# what does texture memory dominant mean in windows phone 8 app analysis?

Tags: performance, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I ran the app analysis in store kit for my windows phone 8 app, I found that app was not responsive and was marked as red, when I select a time range and go for detailed analysis I find this "**Texture memory dominant-native memory allocations are dominating**", with a further bit of googling I found render thread and UI thread's FPS(frames per second) when below desired levels cause this.

What does texture memory dominant actually mean?
How can I get rid of it?
What are performance optimization techniques to maintain required FPS?
Also my layout is pretty simple contains a grid with background image ,a button and an app bar.And also the FPS for UI thread and render thread go below 10, only when I navigate from a particular page to another( say from a.xaml to b.xaml,and b.xaml to a.xaml) from all other pages when I navigate I dont get any issues.(c.xaml to a.xaml or c.xaml to b.xaml)

And my second question is, **I also get a warning saying my UI consumes too much of battery(Yeah UI is pretty bright) and it is recommended to change my color scheme**
Does this really affect the store certification process and are these two issues related to each other?
I would be really glad if people with experience can help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Texture memory dominant-native memory allocations are dominating**: This thing means Your UI is resource intensive. e.g. You have a panoroma view with too mane items. But you are saying you have a pretty simple grid layout with a background Image. So I suspect the background image is not as per guide line , I mean probably it is too large in size.

**UI consumes too much of battery:** generally windows phone uses an amoled or similar display. So some light color consumes too much battery. It is a good practice to consume battery sensibly. Though your app will run perfectly ok.

Comment: That is an interesting point. My app also says that the UI consumes too much battery. But the white background is not "whiter" than the E-Mail hub of WP7/8 or the Light-WP-design.. So is it a problem or not?